# How to define decimel points while minting tokens?

Tags: minting

I am minting some tokens on the testnet by following the instructions in at this document. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gyIOEjxhGhlXsgPtM35DsY3QX02jxLwZSpek7zO4q7M/edit
Everything is working fine and i am able to do the transaction to my daedalus wallet which is running in my local system.

I have minted a token count of 1000 I am able to sent the token of

> 1.12(Two decimeal places)

What i want to do is this I want to sent a token count of

> 1.123456 (Six decimal places after the dot)

I am not sure how can i achive this. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite finalised, but CIP 38 is probably what you're looking for. You define the "decimals" value on-chain in your minting tx metadata.

See: https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/137

The way its achieve before this is off-chain by registering your token with that information here in the token registry:

https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry

In general there is technically no difference between tokens with and without decimals *(except for the amount in existance)*, it's only a matter of interpretation - so its really just about educating the consumer of the tokens about how many digits to interpret as decimals.

Comment: I need to test this before working on mainnet do the above mentioned stuffs will work for test net as well?

Comment: Yes, here's the off-chain registry for testnet: https://github.com/input-output-hk/metadata-registry-testnet

Comment: if i specify decimal places here will i be able to sent 1.123456(Six decimal) Tokens from wallet?

Comment: Yes. Technically you'd be sending 1123456 tokens - just like 1 Ada is sent as "1000000 Lovelace". It's up to the wallet to implement your token decimals in the user interface, but most wallets will respect this no problem. Nami for example will.